# adding/mixing colors in HSV Space

Tags: c++, colors, hsv

I've been trying to get a visualisation going for a few days.
I'm generating a diffraction image and want to color it depending on the wavelength of light.
The easiest way to get the right color was by using the HSV space with H varying with the wavelength and S,V set to 1.0
Alas, I can't find a formula/algorithm/way to mix different colors in the HSV space.

Is there a formula for mixing in HSV or maybe another comprehensible way?

Comment: You might find this previous question informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6130621/algorithm-for-finding-the-color-between-two-others-in-the-colorspace-of-painted

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Honestly, I'd convert the RGB, average the components and convert back to HSV.

It's not the most efficient way, but you'll presumably have or need RGB<->HSV code and the RGB calculation is likely to be much simpler.

Comment: It's more like  1. for every wavelength: calculate the intensity for each pixel. Normalize, add to the **double** Array (picture).  2. Before writing: Normalize the picture Array, scale by 255.0, cast into **int**  3. Finally store into File (raw PPM or with a bit more work PNG)  The only thing remaining will be to check in some way whether the pictures are physically correct.

Comment: I don't fully understand, although it sounds interesting.  If you are normalising RGB colours, you will be projecting them onto some curved region of colour space.  Tbh for saving, these days I'd just write raw bytes and use ImageMagick on the command line to turn it into a PNG.

Answer (score 5):

One of the standard references [Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Graphics:_Principles_and_Practice) by Foley et al. has this to say in section 13.3.7 "Interpolating in Color Space":

> "When two images are blended [...] the colors may be quite distant, and an additive model, such as RGB, is appropriate. If, on the other hand, the objective is to interpolate between two colors of fixed hue (or saturation) and to maintain the fixed hue (or saturation) for all interpolated colors, then HSV or HLS is preferable. But note that fixed-saturation interpolation in HSV or HSL is *not* seen as having fixed saturation by the viewer [...]"

So they agree with the suggestion of @andrewmu, which seems like the best suggestion in general.

Comment: What if you want to mix more than two colors in HSV space (brightness and saturation set to 1)? Can you just add up the color vectors on color wheel? If you add all the rainbow color this way (all the way around the wheel), you should get a white color, right?