# Can images be weighted averaging to obtain one image in RGB color space?

Tags: colors, rgb, hsv, weighted-average

all

I have a few images of one object taken from different perspectives, so some part of the object 
may be in the shadow. I hope to stitch the images to get one big image. I　find the color in the
resultant image doesn't appear correct. Maybe I should average the images in HSV color space.
Can the color can be averaged in RGB　color space? For my case, some part may be in shadow, and the images can be averaged i RGB color space?
If you are familiar with the color theory, please give me some information. Thanks.

Regards
Jogging

Comment: What you're doing sounds problematic unless all the images line up perfectly. But assuming that's the case, I would guess that averaging RGB would work... but only if you average R, G, and B all separately. If averaged as one number, R would dominate. Why not post the image so we can see the problem?

Comment: Thanks，Jere. Sorry, I don't have the images at hands. From the post, 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381366/adding-mixing-colors-in-hsv-space
RGB is an additive model, so images can only be blenderred in RGB color space.