# Combination of colors in font

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts

Hi iam trying to do some program that allowed me to change my font color so if i have used a check box but the problem is the combination of the color . can i combine two colors to make it the color of my font ?

```
Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
                field.setFont(font);
                field.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
```

// can i make this `field.setForeground(Color.YELLOW&&GREEN);
//or any who else idea for combination of font colors . please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE - it seems there is a way :-)

https://github.com/benjholla/ColorMixer (does not seem to be working 100%, see the disclaimer)

see [Adding Colours (Colors) Together like Paint (Blue + Yellow = Green, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139833/adding-colours-colors-together-like-paint-blue-yellow-green-etc)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import colormixer.KMColorUtils;

public class Byta {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        label.setFont(font);

        Color customColor = KMColorUtils.mix(Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW);
        label.setForeground(customColor);

        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: how can i add sir ? what is (10,10,225); ?

Comment: that's why I've posted the link in the end. There isn't such a thing as "blue + yellow = green" mathematically. There are several color models and each one gives you a different color for color add and subtraction. Please take a look on the link

Comment: i will change my code sir . because i like to mix my color if my checkbox check 2 colors because i have 3 colors yellow green white so if i check white my font color is white but if i check 2 colors i need to mix it like i check green and yellow so i need to color of my font yellow green .

Comment: sorry, but yellow green = font with yellow and green stripes? RGB is a color model. You can somewhat convert from this color model to another like CMYK, HSV, etc. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space. Java default is RGB (so 10,10,225 = Red 10, Green 10, Blue 255) - values range from 0 to 255 (max)

Comment: I am sorry, I think I've found it

Comment: i see sir last question sir . how can i concatinate this if i have checkbox ? like i check the two and it need to be Yellow green because the if(Source == check1 && Source == check2)
{
  code here
}

is not working :3 .

Comment: Please see the edited answer. But notice that adding blue and green is not the same for cyan and green (at least for this library).

Comment: its all fix sir . hehehe do you have a color brown ? combination sir ?

Comment: muddy brown sir the combination of red and green .

Comment: do you have a brown sir ?

Comment: Color customColor = KMColorUtils.mix(Color.RED, Color.GREEN); does not look like a muddy brown :-( [but the library assumes equal concentrations for each color, which is wrong). Hard question, huh?

Comment: I give up :-) it seems that https://github.com/benjholla/ColorMixer still needs work. Someone at suggested to port a library of http://krita.org/download to java at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254022/implementing-kubelka-munk-like-krita-to-mix-colours-color-like-paint . I am sorry. I won't go further with this.